# XOR swap Assembly NASM

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, swap, xor

I have to swap Registervariables eax, ebx without creating a new register. It is not allowed using XCHG, CMPXCHG and their variants. 
I tried this but it didn't work. What is the problem in my code. Is the XOR swap the right method?

```
%include "asm_io.inc"

SECTION .data

x: dd 10
y: dd 50

fmt2: db "Value of myInteger X is %d",10,0
fmt1: db "Value of myInteger Y is %d",10,0


SECTION .text

extern printf
global asm_main

asm_main: 

    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp



    mov eax, DWORD x
    mov ebx, DWORD y

    xor eax, ebx
    xor ebx, eax
    xor eax, ebx

    push DWORD [x]
    push fmt2
    call printf

    push DWORD [y]
    push fmt1
    call printf


    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
    ret
```

Comment: It does work but you only swapped the registers not `x` and `y` that you print... you might want to do `push eax` and `push ebx` instead. PS: next time use code formatting properly. PS #2: `ebx` is caller saved register.

Comment: thank you jester. i dont understand how to swap x and y. can you help me please?

Comment: If you want to swap x and y in memory the easiest thing is to write them out swapped: `mov eax, [x]; mov edx, [y]; mov [x], edx; mov [y], eax`. Note that `xor` does not work with 2 memory operands.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by that. Even your code used 2 registers, mine uses 2 as well.

Comment: EBX is perhaps caller saved in some ABIs, but since the ABI is not stated here, it may not be so. On most calling conventions in Windows 32 bit, EBX must be preserved by the callee, but also RBX in Windows 64 bit..

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: All the standard 32 and 64bit ABIs have ebx/rbx as a call-preserved register (see the [x86 tag wiki for links](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info).  Fair point on nit-picking about rbx for 64bit code, though, I guess.  It should be understood that 64bit code needs to preserve rbx, not just the low 32, but worth mentioning for newbies.

Comment: It's not clear what the constraints are.  You said you have to swap registers, so the loads are just a red herring.  Can you just `push`/`mov`/`pop`?  Can you just push them both in the order you want them printed?  e.g. `push ebx` / `push fmt1` / `push eax` / `push fmt2`, then `call printf` / `add esp, 8` / `call printf`.  (i.e. push 2 sets of args for printf before the first call, instead of preserving `eax` somewhere else across the first call to printf).

Comment: In Windows 32 bit as well as in Windows 64 bit, rbx/ebx must be preserved by the callee, not by the caller. What actually must be preserved depends on the compiler and language, and on the calling conventions used. There is not one single ABI.

Comment: One example: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl. This clearly states that only EAX, ECX and EDX are caller-preserved, the others must be callee-preserved. The same for other calling conventions.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: I'm well aware that there are many different ABIs, especially on Windows.  But in all the one I'm aware of, functions must restore `ebx`/`rbx` if they use it.  That's what I meant by call-preserved: calling a function doesn't clobber it.  Some people like the term non-volatile.  Where you said "some ABIs", I was saying "all ABIs", for needing to save/restore rbx if you use it.  At least all widely-used C ABIs.

Comment: I don't like caller-saved / callee-saved terminology; they differ by only one letter.  Also, the -saved terminology implies that actual save/restore happens around the call-site, which is a silly way to write code.  You avoid putting non-volatile data into `ecx` in the first place, instead of `push`/ `pop`ing ecx around a `call` inside a loop.  *call-clobbered* has the more sensible implication: that you must assume it's clobbered after a call.  Actually saving/restoring it is up to you.

Comment: @PeterCordes. I meant that in most ABIs I work with, the function must preserve EBX it in its prolog (and restore it in the epilog), i.e.NOT the caller. I may have misunderstood what you meant.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: Yeah, that's what I was saying; just a misunderstanding.  Most of what I was trying to add was "all ABIs", not just "some ABIs".  Which ABIs let functions clobber `*bx`?  I know there are ABIs I've never looked at, but I just assumed they'd all treat `*bx` as non-volatile because that's the usual convention.

Comment: ISTM we are both saying that functions must preserve *BX. Somehow we simply misunderstood our terminology. Jester said: "ebx is caller saved register" and I corrected that. Then I somehow mixed the two of you up. Oh well, sorry. I find the "call-preserved" and "caller-preserved" terms pretty misleading.

Answer (score 2):

Your xor swap is valid and working well.
It's the print of the result, which is failing (displaying the original `[x]` and `[y]` values, ignoring swapped results in `eax ebx` and throwing it away.

Either add:

```
    mov [x],eax
    mov [y],ebx
```

right after your 3x `xor` block (storing the result of swap).

Or rewrite displaying of results to use eax/ebx, like for example:

```
    ...

    xor eax, ebx
    xor ebx, eax
    xor eax, ebx

    ; prepare stack for printf ebx (new y)
    push ebx
    push offset fmt1
    ; prepare stack for printf eax (new x)
    push eax
    push offset fmt2
    ; do printf eax (new x)
    call printf
    ; do printf ebx (new y)
    pop eax
    pop eax     ; parameters of "printf eax" removed from stack
    ; here stack points to the previously prepared ebx+fmt1
    call printf
```

---

BTW, I would avoid using `mov eax, DWORD x` syntax, as different assemblers may treat it differently. First you can leave out `DWORD`, as that's obvious to the assembler from the `eax` register usage, and then start using `[x]` for referencing value at `x` address, or `offset x` for address itself. So in your code I would write `mov eax,[x]`, as you want to load `eax` with the value at address `x`. In this way your style will be consistent with things like `mov eax,[esi]` vs `mov eax,esi`.

And instead of `fmt1` and `fmt2` you should use more meaningful name, like `fmtx` and `fmty` (to keep it super short, although over the time I learned to not use too short symbols, as then I can hardly recall what that was after few days).